# Light Bulb in Javascript doesn't Turn On

Tags: javascript, html, web, client-side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>switch</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function click_turn() {
            if (document.getElementById("light").src == "/pic_bulboff.gif") {
                document.getElementById("light").src = "/pic_bulbon.gif";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("light").src = "/pic_bulboff.gif";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="light" src="/pic_bulboff.gif" />
    <br />
    <button id="click" onclick="click_turn()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The button doesn't work, that is the light bulbs doesn't turn on. I searched in Google and didn't find any solution. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your code is working fine. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Check your console and make sure that you're not getting 404 for the images

Answer (score 0):

> The [HTMLMediaElement.src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/src) property reflects the value of the HTML media element's src attribute, which indicates the URL of a media resource to use in the element.

Instead of using `src` property, you should be using `getAttribute` to read the attribute of the Element which would not be URL but a value assigned.

```js
function click_turn() {
  if (document.getElementById("light").getAttribute('src') == "pic_bulboff.gif") {
    document.getElementById("light").setAttribute('src', "pic_bulbon.gif")
  } else {
    document.getElementById("light").setAttribute('src', "pic_bulboff.gif")
  }
}
```

```html
<base href="https://www.w3schools.com/js/">
<img id="light" src="pic_bulboff.gif" />
<br />
<button id="click" onclick="click_turn()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `img.src` will return an **absolute** path not a **relative** path so the `document.getElementById("light").src` will never equal to `/pic_bulboff.gif`. You can also add the baseurl to your logic or use `.includes("")` instead:

```
 function click_turn() {
        if (document.getElementById("light").src.includes("pic_bulboff.gif") {
            document.getElementById("light").src = "/pic_bulbon.gif";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("light").src = "/pic_bulboff.gif";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("light").src` returns the full path ('http://etc').

try `document.getElementById("light").src.endsWith("/pic_bulboff.gif")`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I replaced "==" by "endsWith" and it worked. Thank you for all the help.